# Change tty resolution to fit larger screen

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-monitors, tty

I have a dual screen setup:
 - Main screen, 1920x1080 plugged in via HDMI
 - Additional screen, 1366x768, plugged in via VGA

When I switch to tty, its resolution fit the smaller screen. But, as the video output is duplicated into the larger screen, the output on the larger screen isn't stretched, or anything, so I end up with TTY filling only about half of the larger screen which looks ugly on "fullscreen" terminal applications.

Is there any way I can make tty resolution fit the 1080p screen at the cost of text visibility on the smaller screen?

I am using Debian testing.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314406/108618) will help. (Note you need to run `update-grub` after you change `/etc/default/grub`).

Comment: There is a kernel parameter vga= which allows you to set different modes for the kernel boot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I've setup `fbset -xres 1920 -yres 1080` to be executed by root on startup and it worked just like I've wanted, without modifying GRUB config files.